# Query a "Mapping table" to return a specific set of results that contain a specific set of options in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am sorry if the question is kind of generic, it's pretty hard to define the title sometimes.

So, basically, I have 3 tables in SQL:

- a MACHINE table (`id,Name,Description`)
- a OPTIONS table (`id, Description`)
- a MAPPING table (`id, id_machine, id_option`) that basically tells which machines contain which options

So, at some point, in an application I'm developing, the user selects which options he would like to have. Now I need to take those options and, somehow, query the MAPPING table and return only the machines that containing exactly those Options.

Example of mapping table:

```
id | id_opt | id_mach
---+--------+---------    
1  |  Opt1  |  Mach1
2  |  Opt2  |  Mach1
3  |  Opt3  |  Mach1
4  |  Opt4  |  Mach1
5  |  Opt1  |  Mach2
6  |  Opt3  |  Mach2
7  |  Opt9  |  Mach3
8  |  Opt11 |  Mach3
```

Imagine the user chooses `Opt1, Opt3 and Opt4`. I need to return in this case, for example, only Mach1.

I tried already make two `INNER JOIN` between the 3 tables where `id_opt` in (user options selected) but it does not distinguish by machine, it returns all the machines that contain at least one of the user options.

Comment: show us the query that u tried = )

Comment: Please post the type of database but in the meantime, this is often managed by first counting the number of options beforehand, then confirming that the number of rows returned match that exactly.

Comment: select o.id_opt, m.id_mach from MACHINE m inner join map on m.id=map.id_mach inner join OPTIONS o on o.id=map.id_opt
where map.id_opt in ('Opt1','Opt3','Opt4')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id_mach
FROM MAPPING
WHERE id_opt IN ('Opt1', 'Opt3', 'Opt4')
GROUP BY id_mach
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_opt) = 3
```

If you also want the machine name and description, you do a join to bring in that information:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.Description
FROM MACHINE t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_mach
    FROM MAPPING
    WHERE id_opt IN ('Opt1', 'Opt3', 'Opt4')
    GROUP BY id_mach
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_opt) = 3
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id_mach
```

Comment: I think this will return all machines, that have *any* of the selected option, but not *all*

Comment: @hage Poorly worded question, or I'm tired

Comment: Exactly what hage said. Taking my example, your query would return Machine2 as well (since it contains Opt1 and Opt3) but it shouldn't because Opt4 is missing in Machine 2. So it should return only Machine 1 in my example.

Comment: @FlavioJustino Reload the page

Comment: Thanks Tim, it worked perfectly! I just need now to keep track of the number of options the user selects, but that it'll be pretty easy I think.

Comment: Hi Tim. This worked fine for SQL Server as I said before. Howerver, now I moved on to the next steps in my project, and I also need to make this work in an Access SQL query (I didn't know before I would need this). Your query does not work with Access, I get the error "Missing operator in count distinct. It seems that Access does not support count distinct (and I'm not sure about the having clause as well). Is there another way to go around this issue? Thanks so much mate

Comment: @FlavioJustino You should open up a new question.  Reference this one.